# Form dropdownlist change event not triggering

Tags: javascript, forms

I've seearched the site but I haven't found any answer on it. I'm trying to use the change event for a dropdownlist and get the value of it but it doesn't work. The change event doesn''t seem to be triggering. Does anyone know why?

```
var list = document.getElementById('voteSite');
var frame = document.getElementById('frame');
list.addEventListener('change',listChange,false);

function listChange(){
alert("test");
}
```

Comment: Do these both elements: `#voteSite` and `#frame` (whatever elements they are) exist before you try to attach an eventlistener to `#voteSite`?

Comment: Its working here - http://jsfiddle.net/GVYyx/